# Saxon-CE - How do I set the element in which I would like my XSL transformation to be placed?

Tags: html, xml, xslt, saxon, xmltable

I have managed to get my table working with Saxon-CE, however I cannot find a way to specify the element in which I would like my XSL Table placed.

Any ideas?

EDIT:
Apologies for lack of code, was trying to post before I left work. Here is the code:

EDIT2: I have managed to get the result-document to now work, now I just need to style the table! I have updated my post with the working code.

XML File:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="stylesheet.xsl" type="text/xsl" ?>
<leaderboard>
    <row>
        <position>1</position>
        <name>XXXXX</name>
        <class>Mage</class>
        <level>90</level>
        <points>160</points>
    </row>
    <row>
        <position>2</position>
        <name>XXXXX</name>
        <class>Warrior</class>
        <level>90</level>
        <points>155</points>
    </row>
    <row>
        <position>3</position>
        <name>XXXXX</name>
        <class>Death Knight</class>
        <level>90</level>
        <points>145</points>
    </row>
    <row>
        <position>4</position>
        <name>XXXXX</name>
        <class>Shaman</class>
        <level>90</level>
        <points>140</points>
    </row>
    <row>
        <position>5</position>
        <name>XXXXXXX</name>
        <class>Druid</class>
        <level>90</level>
        <points>130</points>
    </row>
    <row>
        <position>6</position>
        <name>XXXXXX</name>
        <class>Monk</class>
        <level>90</level>
        <points>120</points>
    </row>
    <row>
        <position>7</position>
        <name>XXXXXX</name>
        <class>Warlock</class>
        <level>90</level>
        <points>115</points>
    </row>
    <row>
        <position>8</position>
        <name>XXXXXX</name>
        <class>Priest</class>
        <level>90</level>
        <points>100</points>
    </row>
    <row>
        <position>9</position>
        <name>XXXXXX</name>
        <class>Hunter</class>
        <level>90</level>
        <points>90</points>
    </row>
    <row>
        <position>10</position>
        <name>XXXXXX</name>
        <class>Warrior</class>
        <level>90</level>
        <points>80</points>
    </row>
</leaderboard>
```

XSL Stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:result-document href="#leadertable" method="text">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="leaderboard">
      <xsl:sort select="position" data-type="number"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="leaderboard" >
    <table width="1070px" height="950px" border="1" >
        <tr bgcolor = "#cccccc" >
            <td>Position</td>
            <td>Character Name</td>
            <td>Class</td>
            <td>Level</td>
            <td>Points</td>
        </tr>
<xsl:for-each select="row" >
        <tr>
            <td> <xsl:value-of select="position" /> </td>
            <td> <xsl:value-of select="name" /> </td>
            <td> <xsl:value-of select="class" /> </td>
            <td> <xsl:value-of select="level" /> </td>
            <td> <xsl:value-of select="points" /> </td>
        </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
     </table>
</xsl:template >
</xsl:stylesheet >
```

Content Page on my CMS:

```
        <p>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">// <![CDATA[
onSaxonLoad = function() {
        proc = Saxon.run(   {
            stylesheet:     '/mattmodx/assets/templates/imperious/xml/stylesheet.xsl',
            source:         '/mattmodx/assets/templates/imperious/xml/leaderboard.xml'
        } );
    }
// ]]></script>
</p>
<div class="leaderwrapper">
<div class="leaderboard"><img src="[[++site_url]]/assets/templates/imperious/images/leaderboardhead.png" alt="" width="1102" height="41" />
<div id="leadertable"> </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This post is as yet insufficient. You need to provide your code, that is, XSLT stylesheet, XML input and HTML output. Also, be more precise with language: I assume you did not mean "XSL table"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think given

```
<div id="foo"></div>
```

in your HTML document an

```
<xsl:result-document href="#foo">...</xsl:result-document>
```

in your stylesheet is supposed to write to that element with id `foo`. See http://saxonica.com/ce/user-doc/1.1/index.html#!coding/result-documents.

Comment: Thanks for the information. This seems like what I am after, however no matter where I place this in my XSL Stylesheet I am having no luck. I have updated the main post with what I have tried.

Comment: @Matt, well you have `<xsl:template match ="/" ><xsl:result-document href="#leadertable" method="html">` in the XSLT but your HTML does not have a `<div id="leadertable"></div>` to indicate the target element. And if you only want to create a table with your XSLT then I don't understand why you always create a complete document with `html`, `head` and `body` element. That does not make sense.

Comment: All sorted now, I have updated the code in my post with the code that works. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: @Matt, glad you got it sorted. One note: you have `version="1.0"` instead of `version="2.0"`. While it is possible to use `version="1.0"` with an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon CE, it puts it into backwards compatible processing mode meant to help you convert XSLT 1.0 code to 2.0 code. Usually with XSLT 2.0 code written from scratch I would suggest to use `version="2.0"`.